# PHP: find and replace values in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, tree

I have this multi dimensional array in the form of tree.

```
$menu = [
    'records' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => null,
            'name' => 'Food',
            'type' => 'category',
            'records' => [
                [
                    'id' => 2,
                    'parent_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'Breakfast',
                    'type' => 'category',
                    'records' => [
                        [
                            'id' => 3,
                            'parent_id' => 2,
                            'name' => 'Omelette',
                            'type' => 'category',
                            'records' => [
                                [
                                    'id' => 4,
                                    'parent_id' => 3,
                                    'name' => 'Turkish',
                                    'type' => 'item'
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id' => 5,
                                    'parent_id' => 3,
                                    'name' => 'Indian',
                                    'type' => 'item'
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id' => 6,
                                    'parent_id' => 1,
                                    'name' => 'American',
                                    'type' => 'item'
                                ]
                            ],
                            'statistics' => [
                                'sale_qty' => 0,
                                'gross_sale' => 0,
                                'net_sale' => 0,
                                'comp_qty' => 0,
                                'comp_total' => 0
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'id' => 7,
                            'parent_id' => 1,
                            'name' => 'Bread',
                            'type' => 'item'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'statistics' => [
                        'sale_qty' => 0,
                        'gross_sale' => 0,
                        'net_sale' => 0,
                        'comp_qty' => 0,
                        'comp_total' => 0
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 8,
                    'parent_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'Jam',
                    'type' => 'item'
                ]
            ],
            'statistics' => [
                'sale_qty' => 0,
                'gross_sale' => 0,
                'net_sale' => 0,
                'comp_total' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'statistics' => [
        'sale_qty' => 0,
        'gross_sale' => 0,
        'net_sale' => 0,
        'comp_qty' => 0,
        'comp_total' => 0
    ]
];
```

Then I have this another array of log

```
 $log = [
    'ids' => [5, 8],
    5 => [
        'id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Indian',
        'type' => 'item',
        'item_price' => '475.00',
        'item_tax' => '76.000000',
        'sale_count' => '1',
        'gross_total' => 551,
        'complimentry_count' => '0',
        'complimentry_total' => 0,
        'complimentry_net_total' => 0,
        'net_total' => 475
    ],
    8 => [
        'id' => 8,
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Jam',
        'type' => 'item',
        'item_price' => '603.45',
        'item_tax' => '"96.55',
        'sale_count' => '1',
        'gross_total' => 700,
        'complimentry_count' => '0',
        'complimentry_total' => 0,
        'complimentry_net_total' => 0,
        'net_total' => 603.45
    ]
];
```

What I am trying to do here is to search the values which are in `$log['ids']`, in the `$menu` array by matching the 'id' key. If the value is found in `$menu` then replace it with the appropriate array found in `$log`.

For example find value 5 in `$menu` if found replace it with `$log[5]`.

After this is done rest of the nodes which are not needed and are not in the path would be removed and the sum of sale_count etc. of each leaf (item) would be equal to the value of that leaves immediate parent statistics node.

Final array would something like this

```
$finalmenu = [
    'records' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'parent_id' => null,
            'name' => 'Food',
            'type' => 'category',
            'records' => [
                [
                    'id' => 2,
                    'parent_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'Breakfast',
                    'type' => 'category',
                    'records' => [
                        [
                            'id' => 3,
                            'parent_id' => 2,
                            'name' => 'Omelette',
                            'type' => 'category',
                            'records' => [
                                [
                                    'id' => 5,
                                    'parent_id' => 3,
                                    'name' => 'Indian',
                                    'type' => 'item',
                                    'item_price' => '475.00',
                                    'item_tax' => '76.000000',
                                    'sale_count' => '1',
                                    'gross_total' => 551,
                                    'complimentry_count' => '0',
                                    'complimentry_total' => 0,
                                    'complimentry_net_total' => 0,
                                    'net_total' => 475
                                ]
                            ],
                            'statistics' => [
                                'sale_qty' => 1,
                                'gross_sale' => 551,
                                'net_sale' => 475,
                                'comp_qty' => 0,
                                'comp_total' => 0
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    'statistics' => [
                        'sale_qty' => 1,
                        'gross_sale' => 551,
                        'net_sale' => 475,
                        'comp_qty' => 0,
                        'comp_total' => 0
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 8,
                    'parent_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'Jam',
                    'type' => 'item',
                    'item_price' => '603.45',
                    'item_tax' => '96.55',
                    'sale_count' => '1',
                    'gross_total' => 700,
                    'complimentry_count' => '0',
                    'complimentry_total' => 0,
                    'complimentry_net_total' => 0,
                    'net_total' => 603.45
                ]
            ],
            'statistics' => [
                'sale_qty' => 2,
                'gross_sale' => 1251,
                'net_sale' => 1078.45,
                'comp_total' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'statistics' => [
        'sale_qty' => 2,
        'gross_sale' => 1251,
        'net_sale' => 1078.45,
        'comp_total' => 0
    ]
];
```

I have been trying to get this done for around a week but I've only been able to get to the replacement part but not after that. I have tried `RecursiveIteratorIterator` with `RecursiveArrayIterator` but no avail.

If anyone has answer to this it would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.